# C# do i need to create a new table for each patient

Tags: sql, database

I'm making a program, and i got stuck on the patient history part. I'm not sure if I should make a table for each patient, but then it will totally make the program slow at some point because of all the table that i have created. I really hit rock bottom at this. Need some professional advice I'm still new at programming and still want to learn. guys need some help

Comment: This question has nothing to do with c# nor visual studio 2010. It is a database design question

Comment: I do apologize for the wrong tag that I made.. again I'm still new to programming and this website. I will keep that in mind for future questions that i will make THanks a lot for your answer ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You should do a Patient table and a Patient-History table.
How it depends what you need to store at the History table, but Patient-History table should have a foreign key to the Patient table.

Comment: is it possible to connect the patient name to another table containing his history ?

Comment: Sure! As I wrote before, you relate the Patient table with the Patient-History with a foreign key. In your Patient table create a field named PatientId (or something like that). In the History table you create a field named Patient_FK (foreign key, or something). Each time you insert a new row in the History table, you need to add the PatientId to that row.

Answer (score 0):

There must be only one table that contains the history and the patient id (ID from the patients Table) must be referenced in a column. So u can retrieve every patient history with a simple query.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean new table as in Database? While this is viable in some engines, unless you have a particular requirement for it (for example: to separate permissions per patient in an engine that doesn't have per row permissions) you should be using a table for Patients with IDs, and then a Patient ID column in the table for Patient History, with referential integrity (via foreign key) linking them.

For starters, please refer to [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). There are some cases where you may want [Denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) for performance (or in rarer cases for security), yet the general advice is to create the design for the database normalized and then denormalize as needed.

Comment: just a table. i was thinking of connecting the patient name .. to the patient history.. because if my program will just do add patient i dont think that can give a good grade haha. I need to be able to store patient history. and can connect it to the patient so that nothing can be misplaced

Comment: @JohnSheldonCo what do you do when there are patients with the same name? You shouldn't take that risk, this why you need some form of unique identification.

Answer (score 0):

SQL 'table' is somewhat analogous to C# 'class'. So rather than define a new class at coding time for each patient, you instantiate an instance of the class for each patient at runtime.  And so with SQL, rather than `CREATE TABLE PatientJoeBloggs` for each patient, you `INSERT INTO Patients VALUES ( 'Joe Bloggs' ... );`.

Now I don't know what your C# classes look like but I have seen a few patient medical record schemas in my time and I can tell you that you will need quite a few tables. Some tables may have a historical element (consultations, drug therapy, etc) but others may not (e.g. next of kin). Good luck!